# Constructing a map $H^{k}(M,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{k}(M,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I read that on a compact oriented manifold, there is a map 
$$H^{k}(M,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{k}(M,\mathbb{C}).$$
I want to be sure that I have the right map in mind. We don't have an inclusion, since 
$$H^{k}(M,\mathbb{Z})\ni [f]:\text{Hom}(H_k(M,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$$
does not define an element in $\text{Hom}(H_k(M,\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C})$, since $H_k(M,\mathbb{C})\not\subset H_k(M,\mathbb{Z})$. Hence I think we would have to go through the Poincaré duals:
$$H^k(M,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{n-k}(M,\mathbb{Z})\hookrightarrow H_{n-k}(M,\mathbb{C})\cong H^k(M,\mathbb{C})$$
Is this the map that is meant when people talk about "the morphism $H^{k}(M,\mathbb{Z})\to H^{k}(M,\mathbb{C})$"?

Comment: There is a natural inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and $H^k$ is covariant on both arguments, so I'd expect it to be what you are talking about.

Comment: @lisyarus Isn't $H^k$ contravariant in the first argument though?

Comment: Surely, it is, I apologise. This doesn't kill my argument, though :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to use singular cohomology.

Recall that if $C_i(M)$ denotes the collection of singular $i$-chains, then for an abelian group $G$, $C^i(M; G) = \operatorname{Hom}(C_i(M), G)$ is the collection of singular $i$-cochains with values in $G$. Note, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $C^i(M; H) \subseteq C^i(M; G)$.

There is a coboundary operator $\delta : C^i(M; G) \to C^{i+1}(M; G)$ which satisfies $\delta^2 = 0$. We then define the $i^{\text{th}}$ singular cohomology group of $M$ with coefficients in $G$ to be

$$H^i(M; G) = \frac{\ker\delta : C^i(M; G) \to C^{i+1}(M; G)}{\operatorname{im}\delta : C^{i-1}(M; G) \to C^i(M; G)}.$$

So, if $\varphi \in C^i(M; H)$ and $\delta\varphi = 0$, then it defines a cohomology class $[\varphi]_H \in H^i(M; H)$. As we also have $\varphi \in C^i(M; G)$, it defines a cohomology class $[\varphi]_G \in C^i(M; G)$. So there is a map $H^i(M; H) \to H^i(M; G)$, $[\varphi]_H \mapsto [\varphi]_G$.

In your case, $H = \mathbb{Z}$ and $G = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I always took $H^k(M;\mathbb{C})$ to mean the cohomology associated to the chain complex $(C_k(M)\otimes\mathbb{C})_{k\geq 0}$ though. In which case this doesn't work, because then $C^i(M;\mathbb{Z})\not\subset C^i(M;\mathbb{C})$. So is my interpretation of $H^k(M;\mathbb{C})$ incorrect?

Comment: I.e., I thought $C^k(M,\mathbb{C})=\text{Hom}(C_k(M)\otimes\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$

Comment: The reason for this is that I wouldn't know how to determine the chain complex relative to which we take cohomology groups from the notation otherwise. When people write $H^k(M;\mathbb{C})$, is it just always assume that this is w.r.t. integral singular chains?

Comment: See my new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786259/w-r-t-which-chain-complex-is-hk-signmr-computed